Access to ForeignKey fields of another model
I have project in Django Rest Framework where I need get access from Project to ProjectTemplate. But between I have Department model, so I can only connect with Department via ForeignKey. There is some solution how I can handle this?
from django.db import models


class ProjectTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    desc = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    desc = models.TextField
    project_template = models.ForeignKey(ProjectTemplate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='departments', null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    desc = models.TextField()
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    project_temp = models.ForeignKey(Department, to_field='name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


Not sure what the ask is. Assuming you have a Project object named proj, you can access its ProjectTemplate using proj.project_temp.project_template

I would like to have this in form in api and user can choose ProjectTemplate, that he needs @anupsabraham

Project is linked to Department, and Department is linked to ProjectTemplate. You can get access ProjectTemplate from a Project
Solution:
def get_project_template(project_obj):
    department = project_obj.project_temp
    return department.project_template if (department and has_attr(department, 'project_template')) else None 

Do something like this, might helpful to you!
